# Why do I see "define not defined" when running a Mocha test with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs, mocha.js

I am trying to understand how to develop stand-alone Javascript code.  I want to write Javscript code with tests and modules, running from the command line.  So I have installed `node.js` and `npm` along with the libraries `requirejs`, `underscore`, and `mocha`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
> tree .
.
├── node_modules
├── src
│   └── utils.js
└── test
    └── utils.js
```

where `src/utils.js` is a little module that I am writing, with the following code:

```
> cat src/utils.js 
define(['underscore'], function () {

    "use strict";

    if ('function' !== typeof Object.beget) {
        Object.beget = function (o) {
            var f = function () {
            };
            f.prototype = o;
            return new f();
        };
    }

});
```

and `test/utils.js` is the test:

```
> cat test/utils.js 
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({nodeRequire: require});

requirejs(['../src/utils'], function(utils) {

    suite('utils', function() {
        test('should always work', function() {
            assert.equal(1, 1);
        })
    })

});
```

which I then try to run from the top level directory (so `mocha` sees the `test` directory):

```
> mocha

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Calling node's require("../src/utils") failed with error: ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at /.../node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2276:27
    at Function.execCb (/.../node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1872:25)
    at execManager (/.../node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:541:31)
    ...
```

So my questions are:

- Is this the correct way to structure code?
- Why is my test not running?
- What is the best way to learn this kind of thing?  I am having a hard time finding good examples with Google.

Thanks...

[sorry - momentarily posted results from wrong code; fixed now]

PS I am using requirejs because I also want to run this code (or some of it) from a browser, later.

**Update / Solution**

Something that is not in the answers below is that I needed to use `mocha -u tdd` for the test style above.  Here is the final test (which also requires assert) and its use:

```
> cat test/utils.js 

var requirejs = require('requirejs');
requirejs.config({nodeRequire: require});

requirejs(['../src/utils', 'assert'], function(utils, assert) {

    suite('utils', function() {
        test('should always work', function() {
            assert.equal(1, 1);
        })
    })

});
> mocha -u tdd

  .

  ✔ 1 tests complete (1ms)
```

Comment: For me to make it work, i need to install the amdefine module and add these line coffeescript =>> define = require('amdefine')(module) if (typeof define != 'function') <<= into my 'class' file to make it work ( not the test file). This is sort of annoying since need to have a task to remove this after testing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason your test isn't running is because `src/utils.js` is not a valid Node.js library.

According to the RequireJS documentation, in order to co-exist with Node.js and the CommonJS require standard, you need to [add a bit of boilerplate](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#nodeModules) to the top of your `src/utils.js` file so RequireJS's `define` function is loaded.

However, since RequireJS was designed to be able to require "classic" web browser-oriented source code, I tend to use the following pattern with my Node.js libraries that I also want running in the browser:

```
if(typeof require != 'undefined') {
    // Require server-side-specific modules
}

// Insert code here

if(typeof module != 'undefined') {
    module.exports = whateverImExporting;
}
```

This has the advantage of not requiring an extra library for other Node.js users and generally works well with RequireJS on the client.

Once you get your code running in Node.js, you can start testing. I personally still prefer expresso over mocha, even though its the successor test framework.

Comment: thanks!  i don't suppose you would also know what i need to do to get "suite" (from mocha) to be defined, since with the boilerplate my test now fails on that?  also, are you saying that "define" won't work for browser code?  i don't understand your motivation for the alternative approach above - is it "just" a question of style?

Comment: ah, i see your point - you don't want to define node stuff for web browsers.

Comment: That's not too hard, you're missing the ``require('mocha')`` boilerplate. [Taken straight from the horse's mouth](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/test/suite.js) is the answer. (I'm new to StackOverflow, didn't know you couldn't have multiline source code in comments.)

Comment: thanks again - probably won't get back to this til the weekend, but you've been a huge help.

Comment: just in case anyone is down here and confused - the solution to my final mocha question is now described above, at the end of the question (use -u tdd).

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 5):

The Mocha documentation is lacking on how to set this stuff up, and it's perplexing to figure out because of all the magic tricks it does under the hood.

I found the keys to getting browser files using *require.js* to work in Mocha under Node: Mocha *has* to have the files added to its suites with `addFile`:

```
mocha.addFile('lib/tests/Main_spec_node');
```

And second, use `beforeEach` with the optional callback to load your modules asynchronously:

```
describe('Testing "Other"', function(done){
    var Other;
    beforeEach(function(done){
        requirejs(['lib/Other'], function(_File){
            Other = _File;
            done(); // #1 Other Suite will run after this is called
        });
    });

    describe('#1 Other Suite:', function(){
        it('Other.test', function(){
            chai.expect(Other.test).to.equal(true);
        });
    });
});
```

I created a bootstrap for how to get this all working: https://github.com/clubajax/mocha-bootstrap

Comment: +1 for the solution of requirejs dependency loading in beforeEach

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run JS modules designed for browsers (AMD), but in the backend it might not work (as modules are loaded the commonjs way). Because of this, you will face two issues:

1. define is not defined
2. 0 tests run

In the browser`define` will be defined. It will be set when you require something with requirejs.  But nodejs loads modules the commonjs way. `define` in this case is not defined. But it will be defined when we require with requirejs!

This means that now we are requiring code asynchronously, and it brings the second problem, a problem with async execution.
https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/362

Here is a full working example.
Look that I had to configure requirejs (amd) to load the modules, we are not using require (node/commonjs) to load our modules.

```
> cat $PROJECT_HOME/test/test.js

var requirejs = require('requirejs');
var path = require('path')
var project_directory = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')

requirejs.config({
  nodeRequire: require, 
  paths: {
    'widget': project_directory + '/src/js/some/widget'
  }
});

describe("Mocha needs one test in order to wait on requirejs tests", function() {
  it('should wait for other tests', function(){
    require('assert').ok(true);
  });
});


requirejs(['widget/viewModel', 'assert'], function(model, assert){

  describe('MyViewModel', function() {
    it("should be 4 when 2", function () {
        assert.equal(model.square(2),4)
    })
  });

})
```

And for the module that you want to test:

```
> cat $PROJECT_HOME/src/js/some/widget/viewModel.js

define(["knockout"], function (ko) {

    function VideModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.square = function(n){
            return n*n;
        }

    }

    return new VideModel();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9304158/1326147) was not clear enough, I just needed to add this:

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') {
    var define = require('amdefine')(module);
}
```

To the top of the js file where I use `define`, as described in RequireJS docs (["Building node modules with AMD or RequireJS"](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#nodeModules)) and in the same folder add the `amdefine` package:

```
npm install amdefine
```

This creates the `node_modules` folder with the `amdefine` module inside.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use `requirejs` so I'm not sure what that syntax looks like, but this is what I do to run code both within `node` and the `browser`:

For imports, determine if we are running in node or the browser:

```
var root =  typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null ? exports : window;
```

Then we can grab any dependencies correctly (they will either be available already if in the browser or we use `require`):

```
var foo = root.foo;
if (!foo && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) {
    foo = require('./foo');
}

var Bar = function() {
    // do something with foo
}
```

And then any functionality that needs to be used by other files, we export it to root:

```
root.bar = Bar;
```

As for examples, `GitHub` is a great source.  Just go and check out the code for your favorite library to see how they did it :)  I used `mocha` to test a javascript library that can be used in both the browser and node.  The code is available at https://github.com/bunkat/later.