# How to use "define" with Mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm getting started with JS testing, and I decided to go with Mocha.

The modules I want to test are AMD/RequireJS. However, it seems that Mocha is only compatible with CommonJS modules. So, when I run it, **define is not defined**.

So I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303945/why-do-i-see-define-not-defined-when-running-a-mocha-test-with-requirejs) that suggests [this document](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#nodeModules).

If this is really the way to go, I'd define my modules like this:

```
if (typeof define !== 'function') {
    var define = require('amdefine')(module);
}

define(function(require) {
    var dep = require('dependency');

    //The value returned from the function is
    //used as the module export visible to Node.
    return function () {};
});
```

But now the `amddefine` module is not defined when I run Mocha. I'm not used to Node.js, so my question is: Is this the recommended way to test AMD modules with Mocha? If so, how do I define the `amdefine` in my Mocha tests?

Comment: Have you installed the `amddefine` module? Node.js only supports CommonJS modules out of the box. If you want to work with AMD you will have to install this third party module.

Comment: @mbcrute, thanks, can you point me on how to do that?

Comment: Usually a project's Github page is where you'll find the most relevant documentation. `amddefine` is at https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine. To install any third party module with Node you just `npm install <module_name>` so, in this case, you'd run `npm install amddefine`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what you are trying to do to work, you have to install the `amdefine` package:

```
npm install amdefine
```

If you don't like `amdefine` or you don't want to put the snippet it requires in all your modules, I would recommend that you just use [this loader](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader). You do:

```
npm install amd-loader
```

and before you try loading *any* AMD module you do:

```
require("amd-loader");
```

This `require` call could be the first thing in your Mocha test file, for instance. This installs a loader that is able to understand the AMD format. I've used this with dozens of tests without any issue. And I prefer this to putting the code snippet that `amdefine` requires in all my modules.